# My sql record is being automaticlly converted

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table that gets date and decimal from PHP page. 
When insert is being committed to the table, the value of the date, which is (for example: 2016-03-28) is being converted to" 1970-01-01, and the decimal number (for example: 55.55) is being converted to -1991.00, and sometimes to  -1993.00...

I have checked my php $_POST variables and they are being sent OK. 
I also inserted the values to a different table with the same structure and it worked fine. 
I have also inserted manually through phpMyAdmin and it looks OK.

I even duplicated a working table and checked that the structure is the same, and it doesn't help...

Date column is "DATE"
and decimal column is "DECIMAL (32,2)"

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you're inserting/updating an invalid date value, so mysql "corrects" it to the epoch, jan 1/1970. you need to show how you do the insert/update. no idea how the decimal number is getting corrupted - again, show the actual queries you're using that cause this.

Comment: $timestamp = strtotime($date);  $date_conv=date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);        $sql = "INSERT INTO table (id,date,description, section, decimal)VALUES (null, '".$date_conv."','" . $description . "', '" . $section ."',$decimal)";  Thanks!

Comment: and what does `echo $sql` show? Don't put this kind of code into commands. it's hard to read. edit your question and add it there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are inserting a date, why are you creating a timestamp and then trying to insert that? You need to be inserting timestamps into timestamp fields and dates into date fields.

Comment: Becouse I need to convert string of date to as preperation for inserting to DB.

Comment: But you're converting a date in the format of Y-m-d to a timestamp in the format Y-m-d H:i:s to then insert into a date field in the format Y-m-d. Drop the H:i:s and the date should insert fine.

Comment: @VikingBlooded: mysql will auto-truncate datetime->date on insertion into a date field. providing a time value to a date field is pointless, but not "wrong".

Comment: That is true, but it should be, as best practice, corrected. If you can't figure out what's wrong, set everything to a standard and start debugging.

Comment: give us a sql statement containing values that you are actually trying to populate and we can look at those.

Comment: var_dum($sql) and paste it into your question, we'll debug from there.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the answer, Becouse I work late at night, I didn't see that I was sending parameters to PHP function not in the same order that the function gets tham. My bad... Fixed it and it worked.